# Getting old photos from Camera Roll to Photo Stream

Tags: photos, ipod, photo-stream

I have over 7,000 pictures on my iPod Camera Roll. I recently signed up with iCloud but only the pictures I take after signing up with iCloud go to my Photo Stream. How do I get the first 7,000 pictures onto my Photo Stream?

I want all of my photos to be available on any iOS device where I sign in with my iCloud account.

Comment: did you try...Within iPhoto you can select the photos you want to send to iCloud. Select the images you want to send then use the Share button or menu to send to Photo Stream.

Comment: When i press share, my options are "mail" "message" "facebook" "print" and "copy"

Comment: Sorry, I was using the iPhoto on my Mac :( and it does have icloud share option.

Comment: I have a 4th generation iPod. Do you know anything about iPods?

Comment: How many photos and videos can be stored in a shared album?

A shared album can hold a maximum of 5000 photos and videos combined. When you reach your limit, you must delete some photos or videos before adding new ones.

Comment: Okay. How do i get the first 5000 pictures on my iCloud account?

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this by using Photos on a Mac. I connect the phone to the computer and Photos lets me import and then delete the originals.

Once that is done, the Photos app pushes them up to the iCloud Photo Library and the phone has free space to re-download the photos over time.

If you have a PC or don't want to use Photos, you can transfer the photos using iTunes and then use a web browser to upload the photos to iCloud.

Having a computer to do the upload is working much better than having an iOS device which goes to sleep and uses battery instead of wall power.

I've gotten 15k photos into the cloud so far with 10.10.3 and it's been solid for a day. Fingers crossed it stays that way.

Also, as [Buscar웃](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/46541/buscar%EC%9B%83) astutely pointed out - your iCloud Photo Library can grow to arbitrary size but the [Photo Stream has limits](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202299) - 10,000 photos per 24 hour upload period / 25k per month. These limits are only in effect if you don't store all your photos in the iCloud Photo Library using iOS 8.3 or later. Then, you are limited by your total storage space and bandwidth as far as I can tell so soon after release of the product.

Comment: iPod touch 4th gen cannot go past iOS 6.1.6, so iCloud Photo Library is not available for the OP's device.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking specifically to do is not possible. It's also possible there may be a confusion in terms here.

Photo Stream is intended to upload from the device which took the picture, in order for it to be distributed to all of your devices. Pictures are only uploaded from the point where you turn the service on, going forward, and are only stored for up to 30 days. It is not a permanent storage solution. Therefore uploading thousands of photos from your Camera Roll to Photo Stream would not really do you any good, even if it was possible (which it is not).

iCloud Photo Library, which has now officially launched with the release of Mac OS X 10.10.3 and iOS 8.3, is intended to be a permanent storage solution. Original files are uploaded to iCloud Photo Library and each device can choose to download original files or previews (which are intended to save space). Your entire photo library is then available from any iOS device, Mac, Windows (with iCloud support installed) or the web. *Note that your iPod touch (4th generation) cannot upgrade past iOS 6.1.6, and therefore cannot use iCloud Photo Library.*

Since you are looking for a permanent storage option, given the iOS limitations of your device, the best solution is to physically attach it to a computer and import the photos into the program of your choice. If that's a Mac running 10.10.3, you can use Photos and enable iCloud Photo Library. Once you have a newer device running iOS 8.3 or later, you can then enable iCloud Photo Library on the device to view all of your pictures.

Comment: My ultimate intention is to save all 7,400 pictures onto my iCloud account so i can access all of them on any device i sign into my iCloud account with.

Comment: That is not possible with your current device. If you upgrade to a device that can run iOS 8, you can use iCloud Photo Library for that purpose. In the meantime, if you have a Mac that can run Yosemite, upgrade to 10.10.3 and use the new Photos app to import all photos from your device, then turn on iCloud Photo Library. Once you upgrade your device, the photos would then be available. (Or on any iOS device running iOS 8.3.)

Comment: Can an Ipod or iPhone 5th generation run iOS 8?

Comment: The iPod (5th generation) can run iOS 8, yes. iPhones are not named by generations but rather version numbers (the fifth generation iPhone is actually iPhone 4s). iPhone 4s or later can run iOS 8.

Comment: Okay, thank you but how do i put my pictures from my iPod 4th generation to a device that runs iOS 8?

Comment: You have to sync them to a computer first, then sync them from the computer to the newer device.

Comment: I do not have any easy access to a computer. Is there another way or is that the only way?

Comment: That is unfortunately the only way.

Comment: When i do the procedure, will my albums be saved as well?

Comment: No, albums created on iOS do not sync (except for those created while using iCloud Photo Library, which you are not).

Comment: I am signed up with iCloud now so if i recreate my old albums, then will the albums be saved?